# Deploy SSRS Report to Remote Server

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to deploy an SSRS report to a remote server (that is not on my network). I'm not sure how to do this. For a machine on my network, I would just change the TargetURL, but I'm guessing there should be somewhere that I can associate credentials to deploy to a remote server, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: I am also trying to do the same, have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but if someone is wondering about the same question.
I am using vs2017 enterprise. So when you configure your remote url and folder name and everything is perfect to build your project, you hit F5 or deploy your project. Upon successful building vs will prompt you for your report servers credential. Then you do the usual and vs will do its own job. In a moment you will be able to access your report.

Just read about the permission requirements before you try it.

Hope it will help someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I face a similar issue delivering reports to various servers (customers and dev,qa,staging and production.) In visual studio the best way to do it is start a new project for the new server and import the new reports into it. You end up with a new project for each server.

I found TFS / VS unwieldy and my workflow to manage it unfortunately is doing it manually, or using one of a few open source report uploading tools (there are powershell scripts to do it but I find the tools are more user friendly.)

Best thing to start with is doing it manually; which will sort your initial problem.

Save the file out of your report writer to disk.

In Internet Explorer log into the Report Manager of the remote server http(s)://remoteservername/reports and navigate to the folder you want. Then upload the report.

When its uploaded you may need to fix the connection to the database.

Once  you get used to doing this you can use a tool like [reportsync](https://code.google.com/p/reportsync/) to easily and quickly move reports between servers.